# How can I get the intersection of the multi-select sentences in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have made the programming of the MySQL as a beginner. 
So I have met the problem, that is, i have to gain the intersection as math conception.

```
  $sql = "select code_co.code from code_co 
          left join note on note.code = code_co.code
          where note like '%cholera%'
          and

          select code_co.code from code_co 
          left join note on note.code = code_co.code
          where note like '%diarrhea%'
          and

          select code_co.code from code_co 
          left join note on note.code = code_co.code
          where note like '%fever%'
           and 
          select ....";
```

Above my code, from the multiple selection of code, How can I get the common intersection ?
Too sorry that my question is very elementary, but I am very serious.
Please help me.

Comment: In essentially every other DBMS you'd use `intersect` operator - but that is not available in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try some thing like this:**

```
select code_co.code from code_co 
          left join note on note.code = code_co.code
          where note not in
          (select distinct note from note 
         where note like '%cholera%' or note like '%diarrhea%" or note like '%fever%')
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I think you just made an UNION. Guessing you should use AND operator instead to make INTERSECT.

Comment: Ah! intersect!! Is that word mysql's language? Yeah, i'll try it

Comment: Absolutely, not. But "note not in -> note in" change produces what i want. That is, subquery result can be switching other columns. Here is as like "select code_co.code from code_co 
          left join note on note.code = code_co.code" from note result.